# Google CodeStyle for Eclipse formatter shows version warning

Tags: java, eclipse, coding-style, code-structure, code-standards

Style xml is taken from:

https://code.google.com/p/google-styleguide/source/browse/trunk/eclipse-java-google-style.xml

In Eclipse Luna (Version 4.4.1) go to:

1. Window
2. Preferences
3. Java
4. CodeStyle
5. Formatter
6. Import the eclipse-java-google-style.xml

But I get this message:

> This profile has been created with a more recent Eclipse build than
>   the one you are using. Some older settings might be reset to their
>   default values and newer settings are ignored. Please note that
>   upgrading profiles from older to newser builds is fully supported.

Does someone knows the problem? At the moment eclipse Luna 4.4.1 should be the newest eclipse version, so what can I do to resolve this?

Or another question: Does someone knows other good java coding standard compliant format.xml's?

Comment: Just removed my answer as I found out that I've made a mistake when exporting the formatter profile - so the info on Eclipse 4.3/4.4 was bogus, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Work around:

Here's a direct link to the one from before the Feb '14 commit: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/styleguide/0249a38579160e135cbd7eb5099898611683200e/eclipse-java-google-style.xml

Comment: I have the newest version of eclipse and i still get this message.